# La aplicación dot .net maui no ejecuta la app por tener conexcion en sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, app

Tengo una aplicación en dot .net maui que accede a una base de datos en sql server este esta de manera remota en una computadora externa cuando ejecuto el código en windows en otra computadora distinta al servidor funciona a la perfección ya que el framework me permite ejecutar en android y pc pero cuando quiero instalar la aplicación en un dispositivo android si la instala pero no la ejecuta, creo que es por falta de instalacion de paquetes que le permitan al dispositivo android utilizar la conexcion de sql server, informandome del asusnto encontre que en otras app se tiene que instalar el jtds de java, pero creo que el visual tiene su repertorio de paquetes entonces habra un paquete de nuget que me permite utilizar base de datos de android

Comment: ¿En dónde dices que tienes la base de datos? ¿Y cómo accedes a ella?

Comment: En el Android debes activar la depuración por USB y en visual studio ejecutar directamente desde el movil. De esta manera te mostrará donde está el error y cual es la excepción real

Comment: Si funciona la aplicación cuando pongo en comentario el código de sql, tengo la base datos en sql server en otra computadora, el problema no es acceder a ella por que si logro acceder cuando trabajo en Windows de distintas computadoras

Comment: @Davidrj El comentario de @fredyfx apunta a que muestres el código, ya que existen muchas formas de conexión y librerías para ello. Seguramente no todas son compatibles con Android. Por otro lado mi comentario apuntaba a que detectes el error real, ya que el error que te arroja a ti es genérico, yo hice unas pruebas utilizando `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` y me da el siguiente error `SQL Server Pre-Login Handshake (error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)`, es decir se conecta pero no logea por tena de certificados. En mi caso entiendo que se resuelve configurando el ....

Comment: SQL Server, pero como estoy probando contra un servidor de producción no llegué más allá

Comment: Dale una lectura a estas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 luego editas la pregunta con todo lo que has intentado (así evitamos preguntarte cosas que ya hiciste) y con la aplicación de dichas recomendaciones, aumentas las chances que cualquiera que desee colaborar contigo, podrá reproducir tu escenario con facilidad. Saludos :D

Comment: Debes mostrar código e indicar en que línea da el error y cual es el error